# Редактирование свойства структуры в PropertyGrid

Tags: winforms, .net, propertygrid

Загружаю в `PropertyGrid` экземпляр `SomeClass`. Почему свойство `SomeClass.ClassField.StructField` не редактируется в рантайме?
 Похоже, что `SomeStruct` не копируется обратно после изменения свойства, но почему то же самое работает с `Point`?

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    private int structField;

    public int StructField
    {
        get
        {
            return structField;
        }
        set
        {
            structField = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "StructField: " + StructField;
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public sealed class SomeClass
{
    public SomeStruct ClassField
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Структуре `SomeStruct` необходимо задать атрибут-наследник `TypeConverter`, который перегружает метод [`TypeConverter.GetCreateInstanceSupported`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd3a73dd.aspx), чтобы локальная копия структуры с измененными полями копировалась обратно.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(SomeStructConverter))]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    public int StructField
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class SomeStructConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override bool GetCreateInstanceSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object CreateInstance(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IDictionary propertyValues)
    {
        if (propertyValues == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyValues");
        }
        var field = propertyValues["StructField"];

        if (field == null || !(field is int))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid propertyValue");
        }
        return new SomeStruct
        {
            StructField = (int)field
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить, что проблема — в `struct`. Структуры в .NET передаются, в отличие от классов, по значению, следовательно, вы редактируете *копию* структуры. Вы уверены, что вы не хотите/можете/должны переделать в `class SomeStruct`?

Comment: Я же написал

> то же самое работает с Point

Проблема уже решена, подробности чуть позже напишу тут.

Comment: @Flammable: я думал, что `Point` — это класс, ошибался.